# Find data of a given value and if it doesn't exist then find last entry in series of that value data

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, spring-boot

I have interesting question I came across, Let say you have a table in your database that consist:  month, year, interest rate.

You've entry for each month and user is limited to make only one entry for the month and you can just update the existing record. Now, I need to get data by month and year and I have given month and year as parameter and both values are in int.

Suppose you've to get data of 6 month and you don't have entry for that month then you need to return 5 month's data and if that also doesn't exists and so on.

I have tried recursion but that also go under stack overflow exception.

Here is the sample method that I've written please suggest yours:

```
private InterestRate getCurrentRateOrLastEntry(int month, int year) {
        int givenMonth = month;
        if(givenMonth <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        InterestRate cost = InterestRateRepo.findByMonthAndIsDeletedAndYear(month, false, year);
        return (cost == null) ?  getCurrentRateOrLastEntry(givenMonth--, year): cost;
    }
```

Please suggest your thoughts why it's going in infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using postfix to decrease `givenMonth` at your recursive method call. So you call your recursive method `getCurrentRateOrLastEntry` with unchanged `givenMonth` value. The termination condition `if(givenMonth <= 0)` is never triggered. Use prefix to decrease `givenMonth` -> `--givenMonth`.

Comment: Hi @Arne, I have realised after spending hours and then I found so many ways to do it and instead of recursion I used a while loop just to avoid heavy processing LOL.

If this helps readers so the alternative approach I followed is:
`private InterestRate getCurrentRateOrLastEntry(int month, int year) {
        InterestRate cost = null;
        int givenMonth = month;
        
        while(cost ==null && !(givenMonth <1) && !(givenMonth > 12){
          cost = find the data from repo 
          givenMonth--;
       }
    }`